# удалить ключ в многомерном массиве

Tags: php7

имею многомерный массив из которого нужно удалить ключ:

```
$a =
    [
        'ноль' => Array
            [
                'один' => '',
                'два' => 'главный',
                'три' =>
                    [
                        'один' => '',
                    ],
                'четыре' => '',
                'пять' =>
                    [
                        'один' => '',
                        'два' => '',
                    ],

            ],
    ];
```

и массив с указанием какой ключ нужно удалить:

```
$b =
    [
        'ноль' => Array
            [
                'пять' =>
                    [
                        'два' => '',
                    ],

            ],
    ];
```

если бы ключ на удаление был статичным, я бы прописал в коде:

```
unset($a['ноль']['пять']['два']);
```

но массив $b динамичный. array_replace_recursive работает со значениями, а мне нужно с ключами.

Comment: foreach + is_array вам в помощь

Comment: а разве есть рекурсия без цикла? Я уже решил задачу и хотел удалить вопрос, но не нашёл ссылку